# Steeltoe upgrade version 2 to version 3 changes are breaking

Tags: .net, pcf, steeltoe

After changing version of steeltoe version2 to vesrion3 application is breaking

Exception

```
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: 'Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Steeltoe.Common.HealthChecks.IHealthContributor' from assembly 'Steeltoe.Common, Version=3.2.6.0, Culture=neutral,
```

Comment: This will be a lot easier to help with if you share all of the referenced Steeltoe packages and versions in the project.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to say for sure what the problem is without seeing all of the Steeltoe packages and versions that are referenced, but this error can happen if you have mismatched Steeltoe package versions, especially between v2 and v3.

Comment: this was a namespace issue i am using using Steeltoe.CloudFoundry.Connector.OAuth; instead of Steeltoe.Connector.OAuth;

and this fixed my issue